# Access "this" in template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to dynamic create map layers in my template. Therefor I think I need access to the vue instance in my template

```
<template>
  <MglVectorLayer
    v-for="(layer, idx) in lLayers"
    :key="idx"
    :sourceId="'someid'"
    :source="somevectorsourcedata"
    :layerId="layer"
    :layer="this[layer]"  <<<<< I need to get the computed propery (layer1 & layer2) here
  />
</template>

export default {
  data () {
    layers: ['layer1', 'layer2']
  },
  computed: {
   layer1 () {
     return (..somelayerdata..)
   },
   layer2 () {
     return (..someotherlayerdata..)
   }
  }
}
```

When I leave `this` out, I get the warning: `Expected Object, got String ...`

Does anyone know how I can access `this`? Or maybe there is another/better way of doing this?

Comment: This pattern could use improvement.  The clue is in having to refer to the name of a computed dynamically.  Chances are you need only 1 computed which should process all of your layer data and store the processed results in the `layers` item instead of having a list of computed names.  Then you can loop through actual data in the `v-for` rather than the names.

Comment: @Dan This is just an example. The layer can be very different in data

Comment: I understand, so is my example, it's still not a good pattern to refer to computed names dynamically.  Just letting you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a method:

```vue
:layer="getLayer(layer)"
```

```js
methods: {
  getLayer(layer) {
    return this[layer]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since component instance isn't available as `this` inside `v-for`, it can be replaced with `_self`:

```
:layer="_self[layer]"
```

Or if specified dynamic property names were data, `$data` could be used:

```
:layer="$data[layer]"
```